# how to execute a function which is evoked in a child component as a property in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child, react-props

In my app.js file,I've included a Signing component,something like this:

```
onSignin = () => {
  this.setState({ route: "home" });
};

regFunction = () => {
  this.setState({ route: "registering" });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Signin y={this.onSignin} reg={this.regFunction} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and in the component file Signin.js,I've written the following :

```
import React from "react";

class Signin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signInEmail: "",
      signInPassword: ""
    };
  }

  onEmailChange = event => {
    this.setState({ signInEmail: event.target.value });
  };
  onPasswordChange = event => {
    this.setState({ signInPassword: event.target.value });
  };
  onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    this.y;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <article className="br4 ba  b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw6 shadow-5 center">
        <main className="pa4 white-80">
          <form className="measure ">
            <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
              <legend className="f4 fw6 ph0 mh0">Sign In</legend>

              <div className="mt3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6">Email</label>
                <input
                  className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="email"
                  name="email-address"
                  id="email-address"
                  onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mv3">
                <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" for="password">
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                  className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  id="password"
                  onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className="">
              <input
                className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba white-80 b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                type="submit"
                value="Sign in"
                id="clicking"
                onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}
                // onClick={this.props.y}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="lh-copy mt3">
              <a
                onClick={this.props.reg}
                type="submit"
                className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba white-80 b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
                value="Register"
              >
                Register
              </a>
            </div>
          </form>
        </main>
      </article>
    );
  }
}

export default Signin;
```

What I actually expect to see is that,whenever I enter email and password in Sign-in page (front-end part)and then click on submit button,I should see the email and password on the console and get logged in the main page.technically,by invoking the onClick event on the submit button,both **onSubmitSignIn** and **y** property(Signin) should be executed.

but I can neither see the password and email on the console nor can i sign in and take a step further. How should I have onSubmitSignIn and Y executed with just one simple click simultaneously?

Comment: are you getting undefined when calling `onSubmitSignIn` ?

Comment: when I click on submit button and do the following :
              onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn} 
I'll get the data entered as email and password if there hasn't been added a properly formatted email, ie,a data without @ symbol in it.

however,If I enter a normal data(@ sign included) for email and regular password ,nothing appears on the console.

Comment: I added an asnwer for your case. hope it works @BruceB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser gets refreshed when you submit your form, since that is the default behavior.

Use `preventDefault` on the submit event to stop this from happening.

```
onSubmitSignIn = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state);
  this.props.y();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines and it executed both functions:

```
onSubmitSignIn = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state);
  this.props.y()
}
```

Hadn't I written event.preventDefault(); I wouldn't have been able to see the logs. and If I hadn't put parentheses after y ( being a property of the component Signin),I couldn't have called it from the parent file.

thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are getting `undefined` when doing

```
console.log(this.state);
```

inside the `onSubmitSignIn`, this is because you haven't a `bind` to `this`.

so, on your constructor add the following:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signInEmail: "",
      signInPassword: ""
    };
    this.onSubmitSignIn = this.onSubmitSignIn.bind(this);
  }
```

also take into account that your button is a form submmiter, so it will fire an event to submit the form and then refresh the page. so you also have to add the following on your `onSubmitSignIn`

```
  onSubmitSignIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();  // this will stop the propagation of the event.
    console.log(this.state); // this will log your state.
    this.props.y(); // this will call your y function from the parent.
  };
```

Comment: Why should he `bind` it in the constructor when it's already an arrow function?